# Firebase Callable Cloud Function is returning void without a Promise in some cases

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When calling a firebase callable cloud function as such:

```
const myFunctions = require('/path/to/functions/src/index.js');

 myFunctions.myTestFunc(data, {
       auth: {
         uid: myId
       }
     }).then(r => {
      console.log("THIS IS THE ACTUAL RESPONSE FROM CLOUD FUNCTION", r);

     })
```

I get:
Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void | Promise'.   Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

Even when the callable function in question obviously is returning a resolved Promise as such:

```
export const myTestFunc = functions.https.onCall(
  async (data, context) => {

     return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve({success: true});
    });
        
  });
```

It still gives the warning:
const myTestFunc: (req: e.Request, resp: e.Response) => void | Promise

essentially saying that in some case void is returned. However, I do not see how that is the case when I explicitly am returning a promise as above.

Any ideas about what is going on would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try digging in to the definition of the onCall method.  What does the typescript bindings say it returns?  That's what you're getting, regardless of what you pass as the handler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you navigate to the source code for `onCall()`, you will see that it's defined like this:

```
export declare function onCall(
    handler: (data: any, context: CallableContext) => any | Promise<any>
): HttpsFunction & Runnable<any>;
```

You're getting an `HttpsFunction`, which is this:

```
export declare type HttpsFunction =
    TriggerAnnotated & ((req: Request, resp: Response) => void | Promise<void>);
```

You can see the return type of the function type is `void | Promise<void>`.  It doesn't care what you passed to it, that's just what you get - a function that takes a `Request` and `Response` and returns a `void | Promise<void>`.

If you need to call that function and you want to know if it returned a promise (instead of a void) that you can call `then` on, then you will need to check that it returned something non-void, and it will assume Promise:

```
const p = myFunctions.myTestFunc(req, res);
if (p) {
    p.then(...)
}
```

It seems you might want to review the documentation for [testing HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#testing_http_functions), if that's what you're trying to do here.  There's generally no reason to call the function returned by `onCall` directly.  There is a test library to help with that.

If you are trying to create a reusable utility function for yourself, then you shouldn't be using onCall at all.  Just define and export your normal JavaScript function for any caller import to use.

Comment: I would emphasize that the `wrap(exportedCloudFunction)` method of [`firebase-functions-test`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-functions-test) should be used here. The `onCall` function is a [background function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#test-background), but like some other background functions, they are really HTTPS Request functions with special handling of CORS, payloads and authentication for ease of use and the `wrap()` method spoofs this for testing. (links are for OP, not you doug :D)

Comment: Let me ask the more practical question for my purposes then. I am currently testing, but ultimately trying to use this onCall cloud function to perform some database (cloud firestore) updates when called from a service in my Ionic 4 app. Thusly, I need to check both the data and the context. This cloud function can be simplified (leaving out the db updates) in my case as in the following:

Comment: export const myTestFunc = functions.https.onCall(
        (data: any, context: functions.https.CallableContext) => {
    
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 

        if (data && context && context.auth && context.auth.uid) {
          resolve({success: true});
        } else {
          reject({success: false});
        }

     });

  });

Comment: But ultimately you get the idea: I am trying to wrap the success message in a
   promise and then test for that message when it is returned in my test code.
   
   From your response above, it seems as if this is not doable in the way that I thought it may be. I would really like a way to pass back a success message from my function. Is there any way to do this from a callable function, or would I be stuck using an onRequest cloud function that has that response object?

Comment: You can put whatever you want in the payload of your response.  It's just a JS object that's serialized as JSON.  You should be using the provided test library to set this up.

Comment: You are correct. This ultimately worked for me:
  
  const myFunctions = require('/path/to/functions/src/index.js');
  
  const test = require("firebase-functions-test")({
       databaseURL: ******,
       storageBucket: *****,
       projectId: *****,
  
     , "/path/to/functions/service-account.json");
  
  const wrapped = test.wrap(myFunctions.myTestFunc);
      await wrapped(data, {
        auth: {
          uid: myId
        }
      }).then(r => {
        console.log('This is the response', r);
      });